# timestamp for when an app last used a permission?

Tags: applications, permissions, logging

I'm interested in is seeing the time-stamp for when an app last used a permission. After looking around it seems that App Ops had this feature, but it is no longer available. Are there any apps out there with this feature? Would it be possible to create an app with this feature?

Answer (score 2):

[XPrivacy](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xprivacy-ultimate-android-privacy-app-t2320783) shows timestamp for various permissions accessed by app -  requires root

Picture below:

[image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Call it via the 3-dots-menu (upper right corner), chosing "activity log or usage data" – when having the record of an app open.

Comment: Although you should note that XPrivacy requires a rooted phone and Xposed... (Totally worth it)